# Caliburn.Micro App does not Exit when Window is closed

Tags: .net, wpf, caliburn.micro, application-shutdown

Sigh,

I know I have seen this before and can't for the heck of it remember what the resolution was.

The application keeps running even though I close the only window. The Application.Exit event is not fired.

Unless Caliburn.Micro changes the Shutdown mode somewhere later than me, setting the ShutdownMode on the App does not seem to help either.

My hope is that one day, a nice answer appears here and we can all use Google to find this, apply, and be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro doesn't do anything with the shutdown mode. If you want to post this in the official project forums and link to a repro, perhaps I can help you determine the problem.

Comment: Hi Rob, new information: I could pinpoint the problem to some stuff I do with regard to finding resource dictionaries in assemblies. I mark this as answer, because it's true: CM does not do anything with the shutdown mode :)

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and added: 'Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;' in the instance constructor of App.xaml.cs. That seemed to fix the issue for me. I do think it has something to do with the resource dictionaries, since the problem started after I started using them.